# Sylius installation: When do you need to do yarn install?

Tags: php, e-commerce, sylius

According to the Getting Started guide https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/getting-started-with-sylius/installation.html I need also to execute "yarn install", etc.

Do I really need this if I plan to use Sylius in Headless mode?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need it if you plan to use the admin panel.

Comment: ah ok, thought it would just be needed for the User-facing views/frontend, not Admin UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yarn install is required for making the front end and admin panel look as you would expect, without running it all the content will render and the site will function as otherwise, however CSS and JS assets will not be served